# Flutter alertDialog doesnt response truly in larger screens

Tags: flutter, dart, tablet, flutter-alertdialog, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I am using an 8-inch emulator. In this emulator, alertDialog and showBottomModalSheet don't work correctly. It is responding like the screen has half-width. Are there any constraints I have to change in `themeData`?

[image]

Comment: could you include your code too?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use width:100? maybe now it is set to 50% or maybe you have to tell that for screens with over >1080pixels or something you put the with to 100% . Or maybe the alignment it is wrong and you have to set it to center.